# What is the purpose of storing the session in a session store like Mongo-Store?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, passport.js, passport-local

I understand how the process and request flows in passport but what i dont understand is why are we even using a session store when the cookie just expires after the max age but the session in the session store is always there storing the session id even after the cookie is expired!?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use it for analytics. Like how many sessions we had today. Or yesterday. Or for the year.

Also if you don’t use something like redis of mongo, all your memory will get eaten up. Express-session isn’t built for production environments.

https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/556

Comment: ohk so beside above stated reasons, there isnt any meaning in the storage of session data right!?

Comment: No, not really. But I would suggest storing it in Mongo or another database that way if the server restarts, users stay logged in. Also, if I helped you, please Mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: but how does the users staying logged in has anything to do with the storing of the session data as while deserializing we are matching the crediantials against the userbase database and not the session stored database right?

dont worry i'll mark the answer once i am statisfied and have all my doubts cleared

Comment: Yeah, so when you use express-session or another memory bases session manager, everytime the server restarts, the memory is cleared. So, if it is in the database, the database isn't cleared on server reset.

And, passportjs and other login systems store the cookies in peoples browsers in memory and compares them. So if memory is cleared, the user will be logged out. This will not happen if the cookies are stored in the database.

Comment: so u are saying that on every subsequent request the serverside actually compares the cookie stored in user browser to the database where cookies are stored and then after it it check against the database. is this what u wanted to say?